# Custom Control Property Reference Another Control

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, properties, controls

I have been trying to create a property in a custom web control (`DropDownMenu`) that references another control (`Button`) on the page.

This is my property declaration (inside `DropDownMenu`):

```
<Bindable(True), Category("Behaviour"), Localizable(True)>
Private _ToggleParent As Control
Public Property ToggleParent As Control
    Get
        Return _ToggleParent
    End Get
    Set(value As Control)
        _ToggleParent = value
    End Set
End Property
```

And this is my mark-up:

```
<boot:Button runat="server" ID="t1" Text="hi" />
<boot:DropDownMenu runat="server" ToggleParent="t1" >
    <MenuItems>
        <boot:MenuItem runat="server" Text="test"></boot:MenuItem>
        <boot:MenuItem runat="server" Text="test"></boot:MenuItem>
    </MenuItems>
</boot:DropDownMenu>
```

This is what I get as the error:

```
Cannot create an object of type 'System.Web.UI.Control' from its string representation 't1' for the 'ToggleParent' property.
```

Same error if I remove the quotes. I understand I could `FindControl` based on a string representation of the control ID, but I would prefer to pass the control directly through the property.